# Emacsでsimple.elまたはsimple.elcがないと怒られる

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, wsl

お世話になります。

【要旨】
- Emacsをインストールして起動しようとすると「simple.elまたはsimple.elcがありません」と怒られました。
- 検索して得られたワークアラウンドを元に以下のようにしました。
 + /usr/share/emacs/25.3というディレクトリを改名して無効化
 + 25.2を差す25.3にリンクを張る
- これでなんとなく動きましたが、このまま使っていてよいものか不安です。
- 問題の原理、経緯、正しい対応などご教示願えれば幸いです。

【詳細】
Windows10上のWSL上でUbuntuを動作させています。
- WindowsのバージョンはMicrosoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.476]
- WSLはWSL1
- UbuntuのバージョンはUbuntu 18.04.3 LTSです。

以下のコマンドでEmacs25をインストールしました。

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelleyk/emacs
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install emacs25

$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 25.3.2
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of GNU Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.
```

しかし「simple.elまたはsimple.elcがないから起動しない」と怒られます。

```
$ Warning: Could not find simple.el or simple.elc
Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, warnings

[1]+  Done                    NO_AT_BRIDGE=1 LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1 emacs
```

上では警告ですが、実際には起動されていませんでした。

ググったら以下の記事がありました。

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18180/emacs-snapshot-could-not-find-simple-el-or-simple-elc

Answersを読むと
- /usr/shareの下に25.0.50というディレクトリと25.1.50というのがあった
- 自分が起動するEmacsが25.0.50だけど必要なファイルは25.1.50にあるらしかった
- だから25.0.50を改名し、25.1.50に25.0.50という名前でリンクを作った
- それでいいのか分からないけどいまんとこ動いている

ということなので、真似してみました。

```
$ cd /usr/share/emacs
$ ls
25.2 25.3 site-lisp
$ sudo mv 25.3 backup_25.3
$ ln -s 25.2 25.3
$ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 512 Dec 28 11:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 512 Dec 28 11:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 512 Dec  8 21:23 25.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21 Dec 28 11:46 25.3 -> /usr/share/emacs/25.2
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 512 Dec 28 11:26 back_25.3
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 512 Dec 28 11:19 site-lisp
```

見た目上Emacsは起動したんですが、このまま使っていていいのでしょうか？
この問題の経緯、スタンダードな解決法など、ご教示願えれば幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

（以上）

Comment: 確認ですが、emacs25 パッケージをインストールした際に依存関係で他のパッケージ(具体的には emacs25-common と emacs25-el パッケージ)がインストールされたでしょうか？ simple.elc などの byte complile 済みの elisp ファイルは emacs25-common パッケージに含まれていますので、そちらもインストールする必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
明示的にはインストールはしていませんでした。

これまで、

    $ sudo apt install emacs

していず、特に問題も感じていなかったので、そうしていました。

コメントをいただいて、質問時の状況からリンクの25.3を削除し、もともとのback_25.3という名前を25.3に戻し、

    $ su apt install emacs25-common
    $ su apt install emacs25-el

を実行しました。
前者はいろいろ大量にインストールされましたが、後者は全部インストールされているから何もしないでいいと言ってきました。

で、改めてEmacsを起動すると普通に起動しました。
ということで、これで解決？のようです。

emacsさえインストールすればいいときと、依存パッケージを明示的にインストールしなければいけないときがあるんでしょうか。
ご無理のない範囲でご教示願えれば幸いです。
どうもありがとうございました。

Comment: ppa:kelleyk/emacs の deb パッケージを確認してみました。emacs25 パッケージの Depends フィールドに emacs25-common が含まれているのですが、バージョン番号が指定されていません。もしかしたら別リポジトリの同名パッケージがインストールされていたのかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。思い当たるフシがあります。実は、同じUbuntuにEmacsの古いバージョンが入っていて、そのまま設定していたら訳が分からなくなってしまったので、
`$ sudo apt --purge emacs` として再インストールしていました。それで依存関係モジュールも一緒にきれいに消えるという認識でしたが、たぶんこのへんが問題だったと思います。いずれにせよ、simple.el (c)がないよと言われたらemacs-commonをインストールすればいいという学びが得られたので、自己回答してクローズします。本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

自己回答です。
コメント欄にてご教示をいただき、無事解決しました。

以前は

```
$ sudo apt install emacs
```

だけでうまくいっていたのですが、今回はそれに加えてsimple.elcを含む依存パッケージのインストール

```
$ sudo apt install emacs25-common
```

も必要でした。

実は以前、古いバージョンを入れていて、設定がおかしくなったのでアンインストールしました。

```
$ sudo apt --purge remove emacs
```

で依存パッケージも含めてすべて削除できるという認識でいたのですが、それではダメだったようです。
お世話になりました。